# how to submit multiple datatypes (array, string etc.) to the mongodb using Shiny?

Tags: r, mongodb, shiny

I am setting up a form and store the user inputs in mongodb database using Shiny. One of the input is an array, and if I use selectizeInput, all other data becomes an array.

I've thought it might be the sapply function, and tried mapply also but got the same result. here is the part of the code. I added only the part related to the issue.

```
textInput("description"),
selectizeInput("tags", "Tags:", NULL, multiple = TRUE, options=list(create=TRUE)),

 formData <- reactive({
  data <- sapply(c("description", "tags"), function(x) input[[x]])
  data <- c(data, timestamp = epochTime())
  data <- t(data)
  data
})
```

saving to the mongdb:

```
saveData <- function(data) {
db <- #connection is here
data <- as.data.frame(data)
db$insert(data)
}

saveData(formData())
```

Comment: what's the issue you're having?

Comment: if I use selectizeInput, it inserts everything as an array: let's say this is the  input:      `description: "something", tags: ["first", "second"]`, I see in the database as         `description: [0:"something"], tags: [0:"first", 1:"second"]`. what I want is      `description: "something", tags: [0:"first", 1:"second"]`. I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, just needed to add `toJSON` with `auto_unbox=TRUE`. It was an easy solution.